# Regex extract string after last point

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

im trying to extract every file extension of an uploaded file. 
For example:

> example.doc -> .doc
>
> another.example.jpeg -> .jpeg
>
> even.anaother.example.pdf -> .pdf

i know this could be resolved by using regex, but regex are a closed book to me. So i need your help :( please

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extension+filename+php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, don't do regex but use a built-in: [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: @Boern Jeez, downvoting a 6yo answer due to explicitly outlining an *alternative*

Answer (score 7):

Try this regular expression:

```
\.[^.]*$
```

Comment: this should be the answer, he asked for a RegExp

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following regex:

```
^.*(\..*)$
```

Answer (score 1):

in fact, this could be resolved by using nearly dozen methods. strrpos() + substr(), pathinfo(), explode()+end() are examples.